# Why can't I rollback?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I don't have 2000 rep, so my edits need to be approved. But why am I not allowed to trigger a rollback?

I wanted to rollback revision 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12807482/revisions) to revision 2 since the removed link specifies the source as some sort of disclosure.

Won't a rollback of a low-rep user be put into the edit review queue?

The [list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) does not mention a special rollback privilege.